# display different pages content on single page

Tags: pages, templates

I am creating parallax website in wordpress, for this I am using html5blank-stable template. For my different sections, like about us, and contact etc I have created pages with respect to them. But as it is a parallax website therefore its a single page website. Now how can I add or include the pages content on my single page or template(In my case its a index template).

Comment: What theme are you using? Parallax can be on any page template and generally the front-page.php. Your question needs clarification.

Comment: I am using `html5blank` template. Yes I know parallax can b on any page. but for different section in parallax what approach should be followed to display them on single page?or all of the different sections code should be on single page?

Comment: I would use widget areas and populate those areas with a featured posts or pages widget. This is more flexible than using the excerpt in a loop.